# Extend prototype using decorator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, decorator

I want to add method `setStatePromisified` to react component's prototype, I'm trying to achieve this using decorators:

```
interface IPromisifiedComponent {
    setStatePromise: (state) => Promise<void>
}

interface IPromisifiedComponentConstructor {
    new (...args): IPromisifiedComponent;
    readonly prototype: IPromisifiedComponent;
}

function promisifiedDecorator() {
    return function (Component: IPromisifiedComponentConstructor) {
        Component.prototype.setStatePromise = (state) => {
            return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
                this.setState(state, () => {
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        };
    }
}

@promisifiedDecorator()
class TestComponent extends React.Component<any, any> implements IPromisifiedComponent {

}
```

Typescript asks to implement `setStatePromise` method: Property `setStatePromise` is missing in type `Test`. What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: `implements IPromisifiedComponent` means that your `TestComponent` need to implement methods of `IPromisifiedComponent` (`setStatePromise` in your case). Typescript can't know that you do it in decorator

Comment: @Maxx `setStatePromise` method is implemented inside decorator

Comment: i edited my comment

Comment: @Maxx Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: you can extend `React.Component` with `setStatePromise` method and extend your components from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler complains because `TestComponent` is defined to implement `IPromisifiedComponent` but it lacks the `setStatePromise` method which this interface defines.
The fact that you are adding this method at runtime using the decorator is not good enough for the compiler, so you need to let it know that it's ok and you know what you're doing:

```
@promisifiedDecorator()
class TestComponent extends React.Component<any, any> implements IPromisifiedComponent {
    setStatePromise: (state: any) => Promise<void>;
}
```

Also, if your decorator doesn't need any parameters then you can simply do:

```
function promisifiedDecorator(Component: IPromisifiedComponentConstructor) {
    Component.prototype.setStatePromise = (state) => {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            this.setState(state, () => {
                resolve();
            });
        });
    };
}

@promisifiedDecorator
class TestComponent extends React.Component<any, any> implements IPromisifiedComponent {
    setStatePromise: (state: any) => Promise<void>;
}
```

Comment: In other decorators I pass parameters, so I wanted same signature everywhere that's why I'm using `@promisifiedDecorator()`. Anyway, I like your solution and thanks for explanation ^_^